# Why is `parallelStream` faster than the `CompletableFuture` implementation?

Tags: java, java-stream, benchmarking, completable-future

I wanted to increase the performance of my backend REST API on a certain operation that polled multiple different external APIs sequentially and collected their responses and flattened them all into a single list of responses.

Having just recently learned about `CompletableFuture`s, I decided to give it a go, and compare that solution with the one that involved simply changing my `stream` for a `parallelStream`.

Here is the code used for the benchmark-test:

```java
package com.foo;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;


public class ConcurrentTest {

    static final List<String> REST_APIS =
            Arrays.asList("api1", "api2", "api3", "api4", "api5", "api6", "api7", "api8");
    MyTestUtil myTest = new MyTestUtil();
    long millisBefore; // used to benchmark

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        millisBefore = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {
        System.out.printf("time taken : %.4fs\n",
                (System.currentTimeMillis() - millisBefore) / 1000d);
    }

    @Test
    void parallelSolution() { // 4s
        var parallel = REST_APIS.parallelStream()
                .map(api -> myTest.collectOneRestCall())
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println("List of responses: " + parallel.toString());
    }

    @Test
    void futureSolution() throws Exception { // 8s
        var futures = myTest.collectAllResponsesAsync(REST_APIS);

        System.out.println("List of responses: " + futures.get()); // only blocks here
    }

    @Test
    void originalProblem() { // 32s
        var sequential = REST_APIS.stream()
                .map(api -> myTest.collectOneRestCall())
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println("List of responses: " + sequential.toString());
    }
}


class MyTestUtil {

    public static final List<String> RESULTS = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4");

    List<String> collectOneRestCall() {
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4); // simulating the await of the response
        } catch (Exception io) {
            throw new RuntimeException(io);
        } finally {
            return MyTestUtil.RESULTS; // always return something, for this demonstration
        }
    }

    CompletableFuture<List<String>> collectAllResponsesAsync(List<String> restApiUrlList) {

        /* Collecting the list of all the async requests that build a List<String>. */
        List<CompletableFuture<List<String>>> completableFutures = restApiUrlList.stream()
                .map(api -> nonBlockingRestCall())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        /* Creating a single Future that contains all the Futures we just created ("flatmap"). */
        CompletableFuture<Void> allFutures = CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutures
                .toArray(new CompletableFuture[restApiUrlList.size()]));

        /* When all the Futures have completed, we join them to create merged List<String>. */
        CompletableFuture<List<String>> allCompletableFutures = allFutures
                .thenApply(future -> completableFutures.stream()
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull) // we filter out the failed calls
                        .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                        .flatMap(List::stream) // creating a List<String> from List<List<String>>
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
                );

        return allCompletableFutures;
    }

    private CompletableFuture<List<String>> nonBlockingRestCall() {
        /* Manage the Exceptions here to ensure the wrapping Future returns the other calls. */
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> collectOneRestCall())
                .exceptionally(ex -> {
                    return null; // gets managed in the wrapping Future
                });
    }

}
```

There is a list of 8 (fake) APIs. Each response takes 4 seconds to execute and returns a list of 4 entities (Strings, in our case, for the sake of simplicity).

The results:

1. `stream` : 32 seconds
2. `parallelStream` : 4 seconds
3. `CompletableFuture` : 8 seconds

I'm quite surprised and expected the last two to be almost identical. What exactly is causing that difference? As far as I know, they are both using the `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`.

My naive interpretation would be that `parallelStream`, since it is a blocking operation, uses the actual `MainThread` for its workload and thus has an extra active thread to work with, compared to the `CompletableFuture` which is asynchronous and thus cannot use that `MainThread`.

Comment: I have just tried plain old `org.junit` - both 4 seconds.

Comment: @Eugene based off the answer, I just wanted to warn people that you have different results because your CPU has more cores than mine. Can you confirm you have >4 cores?

Comment: I don't have more than 4 cores, I have _exactly_ 4.

Comment: Interesting. Would you mind commenting on what you think of the accepted answer? I'm puzzled.

Comment: I am wondering if this has to do with the java-version that I was using. Can you try 13 for example and see what you get? If you get 4 seconds, I can point you where I think this was fixed...

Comment: Fixed? I don't see it as being a bug: the accepted answer seems right on point. I just tried with JUnit4 (aka `org.junit`) and I get the same results (on my 6-cores laptop, for which I increased appropriately the amount of "APIs" that get called to test the accepted answer). However, I'm on JDK11: can't really bother with getting JDK13.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()` will end up using a `ForkJoinPool` initialized with parralelism of `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() - 1` ([JDK 11 source](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.java#l2358))

So looks like you have an 8 processor machine.  Therefore there are 7 threads in the pool.

There are 8 API calls, so only 7 can run at a time on the common pool.  And for the completable futures test, there will be 8 tasks running with your main thread blocking until they all complete.  7 will be able to execute at once meaning one has to wait for 4 seconds.

`parallelStream()` also uses this same thread pool, however the difference is that the first task will be executed on main thread that is executing the stream's terminal operation, leaving 7 to be distributed to the common pool.  So there are just enough threads to run everything in parallel in this scenario.  Try increasing the number of tasks to 9 and you will get the 8 second run-time for your test.